# How can i set a variable in File.WriteAllLines file name?

Tags: c#

so i have this problem with File.WriteAllLines. I would like to know if it's possible to set a string variable to fill the city name automaticly? And if yes, how can i do that? Here's my code.

```
void GiveALLFreeMuseumsToFileTest(MuseumsContainer museums)
{
    string[] lines = new string[museums.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < museums.Count; i++)
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i] + "Museum Name: " + museums.GetMuseum(i).Name;
        lines[i] = lines[i] + "; Museum Type: " + museums.GetMuseum(i).Type;
        if (museums.GetMuseum(i).Days.Count() <= 2 && (museums.GetMuseum(i).Days.Contains("VI") || museums.GetMuseum(i).Days.Contains("VII")))
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i] + "; Open only at WEEKENDS";
        }
        if (museums.GetMuseum(i).City == "NewYork")
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_NewYork.csv", lines);
        }
        if (museums.GetMuseum(i).City == "Washington")
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_Washington.csv", lines);
        }
        if (museums.GetMuseum(i).City == "Chicago")
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_Chicago.csv", lines);
        }
        if (museums.GetMuseum(i).City == "Charlotte")
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_Charlotte.csv", lines);
        }
        if (museums.GetMuseum(i).City == "Miami")
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_Miami.csv", lines);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_" + museums.GetMuseum(i).City + '.csv", lines);

Comment: I'd recommend you to declare a variable and set it at the beginning of the loop, instead of invoking `museums.GetMuseum(i)` all the time. Something like `var museum = museums.GetMuseum(i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllLines($"Nemokami_{museums.GetMuseum(i).City}.csv", lines);
```

or old school way:

```
File.WriteAllLines("Nemokami_" + museums.GetMuseum(i).City + ".csv", lines);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually added an extra string parameter and then used it with $, same thing